# Error in Fibonacci recurrence proof by induction?

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm working on a problem from a number theory book (Number Theory by George E. Andrews - problem 1-1-11). The text reads:

> Prove: $\displaystyle F_1F_2+F_2F_3+F_3F_4+\ldots+F_{2n-1}F_{2n}=F_{2n}^2$

I started by setting up a summation:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}F_{2j-1}F_{2j}=F_{2n}^2$$

From this, I worked inductively:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}F_{2j-1}F_{2j}&=F_{2n+2}^2\\
F_{2(n+1)-1}F_{2(n+1)}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}F_{2j-1}F_{2j}&=\ldots\\
F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}+F_{2n}^2&=F_{2n+2}^2
\end{align*}$$

This doesn't mathematically work, though. Let $n=3$, and evaluate.

$$\begin{align*}F_7F_8+F_6^2&=F_8^2\\13\cdot21+8^2&=21^2\\337&\neq441\end{align*}$$

Where did I go wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to having the wrong summation, you have a numerical error: $F_8=21$, not $24$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** When we increment $n$ by $1$, we add **two** terms to the sum, not one.

Comment: Grag! Stupid errors. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The good thing is that you actually computed to see whether things made sense. Much more significant than the minor slips.

Answer (score 2):

Your summation is incorrect.  It includes only the terms odd*even, but not the terms even*odd like $F_2F_3$  (also the indices should be $j$, not $n$).  The correct way to write it is $$\sum_{j=2}^{2n}F_{j-1}F_j=F_{2n}^2$$